# What should I do this quarantine?

Tags: weight-loss, bodyweight-exercises, body-fat, home-exercise

I am 18 years old and trying to reduce my body fat percentage. Unfortunately, while this quarantine has finally given me the chance to, it has also taken out my best means. I used to jog, and often cycled on the weekends. While I am trying to control my diet too, I would really like to exercise too. I don't have much space, neither do I have any equipment (there should be a pair of dumb-ells but I can't find them :( ). I am not particularly strong (could do 10 push-ups in one go last year but struggle with 5 now). I have the time since I am sleeping early to wake up at 6 so I would like some recommendations on what I should do.

TLDR: I want to lower my body fat percentage but also become stronger. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Staying healthy and in shape while quarantined is totally doable.

First and foremost, you can download many apps that start with workout routines from beginner to an advanced athlete like Nike training club. Also, many athletic and sports equipment companies offer free workout plans through Instagram accounts either live or IGTV.

Also, you can have your workout routine at your pace simply by using your body weight without any equipment required.

Some exercises are :

Upper Body
Triceps dips, Push-ups, Side plank, Plank ups

Lower Body
Squat, Side Lunges, Back lunge and lift, Curtsy Lunge, Calf Raises, Wide leg open-toe squat

Core exercises
Superman, Cobra, Ab Curl hollow hold, Side-Lying Inner Thigh, Side-Lying outer Hip, Crunches , burpees and jumping jacks

Most of these exercises I 've done to my workout routines and are great. Also, I would suggest buying an elastic band which is inexpensive, and you can take it with you everywhere. You can take it even when running to do some stretching and you can make your workout routine a bit more challenging.

Furthermore, if you find something (like a tree branch or something) to do pull-ups, I recommend it as pull-ups are a great form of exercise.

From the above exercise, you can mix and match accordingly. You can find more info and videos of these exercises here.

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: I already use Nike training club :) However, I would like some recommendation. I often did exercises on a carpet but certain exercises really hurt my knees, such as dog-to-superman. How should I proceed? Additionally, today I was on day 2 of the NTC routine and while I had enough stamina left, my shoulders gave out after 6 YTWs. I am concerned so I left my workout unfinished. Luckily, my shoulders are back to normal now but I am deeply concerned about whether this is a serious problem or not. I did some more YTWs later on and my shoulders seem fine, but I'd rather not risk anything.

Comment: Dear Mohammad, can you define knee pain? Do you have any known conditions? If you are doing exercises on a carpet usually this should not be a problem. You might consider buying a cushion for you knees or a thick exercise mat. Regarding your shoulders, again if you have not any condition, just scale the exercises or do them slower and lighter until shoulders get stronger. Hope this helped :)

Comment: You could say that the carpet is a bit stiff. I could do some on the bed but the bed is too soft at times so I was in a dilemma. Basically, it felt like doing it on the floor but less stressful.

Comment: If you exclude nearsightedness, I have no medical conditions.

Comment: That's great then :). Then you can proceed to all exercises:)

Comment: The answer should also feature nutrition and sleep, which are (rightly) featured in the context of the question. Permanently adopting a hypo-caloric diet and sleeping enough are essential terms of the equation.